# How to check if the current user can do something in view?

Tags: authentication, playframework-2.0

For example, if the current user is admin, the `Admin` button will show.

How to implement this in play2? Is there a standard solution? I don't find any built-in examples demonstrate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no built-in authorization mechanism inside Play.
You could write your own code to do that (maybe it's just as simple as to look up a flag from a `User` object). And then there's [Deadbolt 2](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2). I have not tried it myself, but it looks great. And can do lots of stuff. :)

Comment: I'm the author of Deadbolt (1 and 2) and Carsten is right - you can do this very simply with Deadbolt.

Answer (score 0):

Check `zentasks` sample, there you can find also find basics of the authentication. I think you can fit it to your needs.